How to import dbutils module in Python on Databricks
In Databricks Python notebook I can easily use dbutils module.
Now I also would like to use it within plain Python file which I import into Databricks notebook
Here is an example.
Here is content of some_python_module.py
secret_value = dbutils.secrets.get("some_location", "some_secret")

Later on I am importing it in Databricks notebook
import some_python_module.py

But I get error message: NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined
I tried to add import statement into my some_python_module.py
import dbutils

but it returns: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbutils'
Aslo dbutils.secrets.get("some_location", "some_secret") works fine in Databricks notebook

any chance you are using the Azure databricks?

@DileepRajNarayanThumula, Yes, I am

have you tried 'from pyspark import dbutils' ? or
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
?

@AdForte, thank you. Now I need to import SparkSession

@AdForte I tried from pyspark.sql import SparkSession but got back  cannot import name 'SparkSesson' from 'pyspark.sql' (/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/__init__.py)

@user1700890 and with this "from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession" ?

@AdForte. All your suggestions worked. Thank you!

As you want to import the python file into Azure databricks workspace.
I have created the below python file and uploaded the file to my filestore dbfs path:
try:
    import IPython
    
    dbutils = IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
except (ImportError, KeyError):
    
    dbutils = None
if dbutils:
    secret_value = dbutils.secrets.get("Key-vault-secret-dbx", "secretkv")
else:
    secret_value = "dbutils not available"

In the above code I have used
import IPython
dbutils = IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]

It is used to access the dbutils object in a Databricks notebook's environment when it is not directly available in the imported module.
So basically Accessing dbutils from the Databricks notebook's IPython environment
I have tried to retrieve a secret using the below:
import sys
sys.path.append("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/")
import dilip_module
print(f"Retrieved secret value: {dilip_module.secret_value}")

Results:

Retrieved secret value: [REDACTED]



@user1700890 can you please check if the solution helped you?

dbutils is a variable/instance-of-DBUtils-class.
You can create your own instance of DBUtils if you like.
dbutils = DBUtils(SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate())

From my conftest.py for pytest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def spark_session():
  yield SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def is_running_on_databricks_cluster(spark_session: SparkSession):
  return spark_session.conf.get('spark.app.name') == 'Databricks Shell'

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def dbutils(spark_session: SparkSession, is_running_on_databricks_cluster):
  if is_running_on_databricks_cluster:
    from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils

    yield DBUtils(spark)
  else:
    yield MagicMock()


